# Microsoft Graph - Can't get users Windows AD groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

When I use:

```
string graphRequest = $"{graphResourceUri}/me/memberOf?api-version=1.6";
```

I get an empty array because my logged in user isn't a member of any *Azure* Groups (I'm assuming).

What I want is to get the list of Windows Domain Active Directory groups this user is a member of.  Is there no way to retrieve this?  I don't care about Azure groups.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was because we didn't sync any groups between our Active Directory and Azure, we only synced users.  After syncing the necessary AD group now it shows up when I query the user's group member within Azure.